# How to solve crash due to read access violation(0xFFFFFFFFFF) in cpp

Tags: c++, exception, wxwidgets

I am using `wxTextCtrl *m_displayNameText;` in header file. In constructor I am adding following code

```
m_displayNameText = new wxTextCtrl(m_panel, wxID_ANY, "some name", ...);
```

I am accessing it in some other function :

```
if (m_frame->m_displayNameText)
{
        m_displayName = wxStringToUTF8String(m_frame->m_displayNameText->GetValue());
}
```

Here it shows following exception when I analyzed the dump. It is not always reproducible. How can we prohibit this exception? I am adding NULL check but it seems that it is not sufficient.
Unhandled exception thrown: read access violation.
`m_frame->m_displayNameText` was `0xFFFFFFFFFF`.

Comment: it looks like m_frame is not always initialized.

Comment: We cannot find UB elsewhere in your code...

Comment: Either `m_frame` or `m_frame->m_displayNameText` is invalid. Run your program with your favorite debugger and as soon as it crashes inspect the relevant variables. You don't know how to use a debugger? Then it's time to start learning it now.

Comment: @ArkadyGodlin m_frame is initialized, memory access violation is for m_displayNameText->GetValue() as exception is : "read access violation. m_frame->m_displayNameText was 0xFFFFFFFFFF"

Comment: You should pull out a debugger. All debuggers know how to break on invalid memory access and then you can inspect which value was not correctly initialised. You should also try [UBSan](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer.html) (the same options exist also in gcc) and [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (on Linux) or [Dr.Memory](http://www.drmemory.org/) (also on Windows).

Comment: oh i thought the error is on the if check. anyway you should set m_displayNameText to nullptr in the constructor of the m_frame object. and not leave it to compiler.

Comment: @aromahola we can't help much here. Corruption somewhere else in your program might be the cause.

Comment: @aromahola, try to: 1) add debug statements to the places where the pointer is set and used to narrow down the part of the code where it breaks and 2) try the Dr.Memory tool to catch invalid memory accesses.

Comment: @aromahola set the value to nullptr at constructor of Frame, then check for if (m_frame->m_displayNameText != nullptr) if it true and later to you the error, then it is some kind of memory corruption that you will need to look for, if it is value is nullptr then it is just value creation is the problem.
also check that when you do destructor, move you set value to nullptr, this will help to debug.

Comment: "It is not always reproducible" I would start with why this is the case.  Are you using threads for example and not using a mutex where you should be?  Are you trying to copy too much data to something elsewhere in that struct and trashing other data?  There's nowhere near a minimal reproducible example here; and since it doesn't reproduce with the full code I think you need to work out why

Comment: @aromahola, you know where the crash is, but not where the *cause* is. The cause is long, long before the actual crash, because a pointer should never ever be set to that value. So what you need to do is find where, how and why it gets set to it.

Comment: consider use smart pointer, not raw pointer. your pointer may be unintialized or deleted when use. for debug purpose, you can set read/write watch point.

Comment: One non-obvious reason for the wonky 0xffffffff address is an alignment fault.  Produced by a SIMD instruction that requires its operand to be aligned to 16.  That instruction should be readily visible in the minidump, as well as the value of the ESP register.  VS2013 RTM had a stack alignment bug.

Comment: Intialize `m_displayNameText` to NULL before using it (e.g. at the m_frame ctor). Also follow the path from the creation of the `wxTextCtrl` to its use.

Comment: @aromahola, are you accessing the GUI from the secondary thread? It sure sounds like it, especially since you said that the crash not always reproducible,